# Automatic animation with iBooks Author

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, ibooks, ibook-author

I am trying to create animations in an ebook (using iBooks Author) much like the the first few pages of Yellow Submarine ebook.

Specifically I want to have animations in the content and immediately animate and interactable without the need to trigger (touch to turn on) a widget. I tried HTML5 (like the sencha demo) as well as keynote. But both of those ended up creating a selectable widget where the animation would not happen w/o selecting the widget.

Comment: It is not totally clear from your question what your doing or what language your trying to do it in. Are you using iBook-Author? I added the tag.

Comment: I am trying to create an ebook (to be distributed through iBooks) using iBooks Author as my authoring tool.

Comment: I would love to know of a way to do this as well... even if I have to hack something -- as long as apple still approves it :)

Comment: @PeterKing what did you end up doing? Making the book in Adobe? This is a huge hurdle in a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

Why not sync the book which has the functionality you want to iTunes? - Then find the book which is then synced to your PC/Macs hard drive and open it in an editor and look at the XML/Pub 3 script. This may give you some clues as to how they are doing it.

The iBook format is an Apple extended version of [EPub v 3](http://idpf.org/epub/30)

I would be very surprised if it can't be done from the IBooks Author tool.

If the Book you wish to examine has DRM you could still look at it by using a tool like:
[**Requiem 3.3**](http://cydiablog.com/crack-apple-ibooks-drm-requiem-3.3-app/)

Comment: The Yellow Submarine ebook from iBook is DRM locked so I cant open it with Sigil. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you seen this? http://cydiablog.com/crack-apple-ibooks-drm-requiem-3.3-app/ lets remove the DRM so you could see how it is done.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, but (I was told that) unfortunately The Beatles yellow Submarine.epub can not be decrypted even by Requiem 3.3. I think unfortunately I will be going the app-route.

Comment: Just to make it clear I'm not pro breaking DRM! I make my living from selling software, its just it can sometimes help to pull someone's  code or example apart to see how to do something....

Answer (score 0):

@Peter
this is all hacking. 
When you have time consider requesting this feature:
[iBooks Author feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ibooks-author.html)

regards,
Peter